# Resharper wants to add something before parameter

Tags: c#, resharper

This is probably a very silly question, but I have resharper installed and it is trying to do something that I don't know the purpose of.

In my code I have the following.

```
double.Parse(cmbShiftStartMinute.Text) % 5 == 0
```

It wants to add a "s:"

```
double.Parse(s: cmbShiftStartMinute.Text) % 5 == 0
```

What does that do?

Comment: When you say 'it is trying to do something', do you in fact mean it is offering a [Context Action](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Context_Actions)? A Context Action is simply something R# *can* do, as opposed to a [Quick Fix](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Quick-Fixes), which is more what is *wants* to do.

Comment: Yes, it is a Context Action.  I always like to see what it is offering because sometimes it does things that I have no idea what they are (like this question) and then I have learned something new.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

In this case, it won't change the function of the code in any way.  In theory it can be used to re-order the parameters or specify optional arguments without specifying some that come before it.

In theory it could add clarity to the code, if the purpose of the parameter wouldn't be clear without the named parameter, but I don't see that being the case here, as `s` isn't a very descriptive parameter name.

Comment: You say "In this case..." for clarity could using named arguments ever change the function of the code?

Comment: @DaveParsons As the answer says, "In theory it can be used to re-order the parameters or specify optional arguments without specifying some that come before it."  The latter being means of potentially functionally changing how the method is called, as it means not needing to explicitly specify certain optional arguments.  Resharper of course wouldn't do a refactor like that on its own, but named parameters can be used to do that.

Comment: I see, I was reading unnecessary ambiguity into your phrase "function of the code" - I was reading that to mean function of the underlying method code when of course you mean function of the code written to call the method.

Comment: @DaveParsons. Imagine you have a method `myMethod(string s = "a", string b = "b")` If you call `myMethod("v")`, this wouldn't be the same as `myMethod(b:"v")`. But they are no optional arguments in double.Parse, so... resharper is doing weird things (maybe some options you checked ?)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the overloads of Double.Parse you will find 4 methods. The string parameter is called "s":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx

Resharper replaces your parameter by a named parameter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

I think you should be able to disable that somewhere in the options.